# SQL Multiple Checking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select some data with the query below, but my "not equal to" condition is not limiting my results correctly. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
Select 
   JobCode,
   CurrentStatus 
From 
   JobDetails 
Where 
     (CurrentStatus <> 'Pending for Sparepart' or CurrentStatus <> 'Swap Requested' or CurrentStatus <> 'External Repair')
     AND (CompletionDate IS NULL AND AssignDate IS NOT NULL) 
     AND (TechCode='Tech')
```

Comment: OR <> OR <> will always be true. Perhaps you want `where CurrentStatus NOT IN ('Pending for Sparepart', 'Swap Requested', 'External Repair')`.

Comment: 'Pending for Spacepart' is a match for the criteria `CurrentStatus <> 'Swap Requested'`, therefore it will be returned in the results despite the first part of your or statement. Doing what @jarlh suggested should work.

Comment: thanks jarlh thats it. :)